# Participant Count and Capturing additional participant information

Tags: civievent, price-sets, participants

If I am using a Price Set field with a multiple participant count (Say, Five registrants for a discounted price of $550) will or can I also capture the additional registrant information.

to expound:

We have individual registration options, as well as a group registration option.  I was planning on doing
- 1 price field for General registrant (Participant count of 1)
- 1 price field for Student registrant (Participant count of 1)
- 1 price field for Group of Five (Participant count 5)

Do I need to activate the "Register additional participants" option in order to capture the additional participants names or will civi prompt for that info since the participant count is 5 for the Group of Five option.

If I do have to select the "Register additional participant" setting, would the registrant have to both select 4 from the Register Additional Participants drop down as well as select the "group of 5" option?  if this is the case, should the group of 5 participant count really be 1 instead of 5?

Thanks

Comment: If you need more complex set ups then it is worth mentioning your CMS as there may be options such as webform_civicrm or caldera-forms that can help bend the laws of the civi universe

Comment: Sorry, we are on Joomla

Answer (score 1):

Yes - typically you would activate "register additional participants" to capture the additional names.  The participant count being 5 will NOT trigger this.  That workflow is preferred when someone is, say, buying a table of 10 for a fundraiser gala but doesn't know who will be attending.  And yes - the participant count should be "1" in this case.

Comment: It would be nice if your participant count is more than 1 that you could choose whether or not to collect guest info.  

I don't seem to see on option that allows us to have realtime data.  Either our numbers will be an underestimate because our Group of 5 participant count is set to 1 or if we set it to 5 then later get the names of the additional participants and add them to the event it will cause the participant count to be inflated.  I though of possibly breaking down the group of 5 pricing to the individual price, but there is no way require 5 registrants in order to get that pricing.

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends on what counts as 'additional information'. For example you could have a Profile that has (Participant-based) fields for the names of Persons 2 - 5, so this does not create Contact records for them, but you do know who they are.